# Como utilizar write para escrever em hexadecimal na porta serial

Tags: c#, porta-serial

Tenho uma rotina em java para imprimir em porta serial.
Preciso passar esta rotina para c#   são bem semelhantes, mas acredito ter esbarrado em algumas diferenças:

```
        byte btCmds[] = new byte[200];
        stValue = "748";      //Banco
        btCmds[1] = (byte)0xA2;    
        btCmds[0] = 0x1B;    
        for(wdCnt=0;wdCnt < stValue.length() ;wdCnt++ ){
            btCmds[wdCnt+2] = stValue.getBytes()[wdCnt];
            }
            btCmds[wdCnt+2] = 0x0D;
            szCmds = wdCnt+3;     
            for(int Count = 0;Count <  szCmds; Count ++) 
                { serialPort.writeByte(btCmds[Count]); }
```

minha principal dúvida é no comando: Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
não entendi a sintaxe. Se eu tenho que fazer um loop como no java e vai imprimindo caracter por caracter ou se ele ja controla isso colocando:
***{serialPort.Write (btCmds[Count],0,szCmds); }***
outra dúvida: byte btCmds[]  ou char 
desde já agradeço